# How to check POST Request is sended to Server in JSON web service

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services, post

In my app I want to check the Authentication For Login. But when I post request I don't know if my request has reached the server.

Here is my code...

```
 -(void)clearsession
 {

   NSString *username = @"tiger@gmail.com" ;

   NSString *password = @"password";

  NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.b24solutions.com/grocery/MyLogin.php"];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:0.0];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@ password=%@",username,password];

NSLog(@"string that post:%@",postString);
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *clearSession = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 [clearSession start];
NSLog(@"%@",clearSession);
if(clearSession){
    NSLog(@"data send");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}
}
```

and rather NSURLConnection method are same as defined.

In this app I send the username and password in a JSON format. If the user name is already register then it receives response `status=1` otherwise `status=0`.  but when I send registered username and password then the response will be received as status=0 why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I checked you need the ampersand. Try changing this:

`@"username=%@ password=%@"`

To this:

`@"username=%@&password=%@"`

Comment: thanks dear. Actually error in the format of parameter  that i  passed and send on POST.